# custom error page is not working with .htaccess or Apache & nginx Settings

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, plesk, custom-error-pages

I have created a 404 page for my project and for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work. when going to a non URL I get a white page with "File not found".

`www.example.com/wrongurl` i get a white page file not found

`www.example.com/wrongurl.php` i get a white page file not found

`www.example.com/wrongurl.html` i get my custom 404 page

I have tried both .htaccess file and the Apache & nginx Settings via my Plesk panel

My .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Append trailing slash if omitted (canonical redirect)
RewriteRule ^news$ /$0/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)article_slug=([\w-]*)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ /news/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]*)$ /news.php?article_slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Apache & nginx Settings
[image]

**To troubleshoot the issue I have done the following**

1. Checked that my .htaccess file is being processed properly. I added an invalid line to it, (foo bar), and tried to access a non-existent page. and I got the Internal Server Error instead of "File not found".
2. I have Checked that my custom error page is located in the correct
   directory and has the correct permissions. And I can access my error
   page directly by typing the URL into my browser to see if it
   loads.
3. My Apache configuration allows custom error pages.
4. I have tried to use the absolute path for my ErrorDocument directive. Instead of using a relative path like ErrorDocument 404 /404.php, I have tried using the absolute path like ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/html/404.php

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to let you know. Using a PHP session to measure attempts just makes no sense. Quite obviously, one can just delete a session cookie and make a clean slate request.

Comment: thank you for your comment, to be honest, I didn't even think of that and it makes perfect sense i deleted the post so i could restructure the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to do with how PHP is installed on your server. Any URL with a `.php` extension is likely proxied (using Nginx? You mention both Nginx and Apache) to the PHP executable, completely bypassing Apache/`.htaccess`.

When you request a URL of the form `/wrongurl` then your last rule is internally rewriting this to `/wrongurl.php` and it's this that is generating the "white page file not found" response.

You can at least prevent `/wrongurl` from being rewritten to `/wrongurl.php` and bypassing your custom 404 by first checking that the target file exists before rewriting the request. In other words, change the last rule from this:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

So, instead of rewriting the request when the requested URL does not map to a file. Only rewrite the request when the corresponding `.php` file exists.

No need to backslash-escape literal dots inside a regex character class. And no need for the `NC` flag on that rule either.